# Mutliprocessing Queue vs. Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out the difference in usage between `multiprocessing.Pool` and `multiprocessing.Queue`.

To help, this is bit of code is a barebones example of what I'm trying to do.

```
def update():
    def _hold(url):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
        return soup
    def _queue(url):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
        li = [l for l in soup.find('li')]
        return True if li else False

    url = 'www.ur_url_here.org'
    _hold(url)
    _queue(url)
```

I'm trying to run `_hold()` and `_queue()` at the same time. I'm not trying to have them communicate with each other so there is no need for a `Pipe`. `update()` is called every 5 seconds.

I can't really rap my head around the difference between creating a pool of workers, or creating a queue of functions. Can anyone assist me?

The real `_hold()` and `_queue()` functions are much more elaborate than the example so concurrent execution actually is necessary, I just thought this example would suffice for asking the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Pool` and the `Queue` belong to two different levels of abstraction.

The Pool of Workers is a concurrent design paradigm which aims to abstract a lot of logic you would otherwise need to implement yourself when using processes and queues.

The `multiprocessing.Pool` actually uses a `Queue` internally for operating.

If your problem is simple enough, you can easily rely on a `Pool`. In more complex cases, you might need to deal with processes and queues yourself.

For your specific example, the following code should do the trick.

```
def hold(url):
    ...
    return soup

def queue(url):
    ...
    return bool(li)

def update(url):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        hold_job = pool.apply_async(hold, args=[url])
        queue_job = pool.apply_async(queue, args=[url])

        # block until hold_job is done
        soup = hold_job.get()
        # block until queue_job is done
        li = queue_job.get()
```

I'd also recommend you to take a look at the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent%20futures#module-concurrent.futures) module. As the name suggest, that is the future proof implementation for the Pool of Workers paradigm in Python.

You can easily re-write the example above with that library as what really changes is just the API names.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know I could call `apply_async()` more than once. I will look into `futures`